# What is Krosyn?

Tags: poetry, belarusian-language, like-water-like-fire, pauliuk-bahrym

"Play then, play" by Pauluk or Paŭli︠u︡k Bahrym (in the poetry anthology *Like Water, like Fire*) contains the following lines:

> ... But the bagpipes I must play, for
> I in Krosyn cannot stay more
>
> A Lord in Krosyn rages harshly,
> And with clubs they slew my father

I assume that Krosyn is a place, but I have been unable to discover exactly where this is or the significance of that location. Did something specific happen there that this poem is referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I should have read the introduction more carefully. Krosyn was, in fact, a small village in Belarus. From the anthology's introduction:

> In 1828, when a liberalminded Catholic priest opened a parish school in his native village of Krosyn, he found to his surprise and delight that one of the serg-boys Who attended it, the 15-year-old Pauluk Bahrym, showed considerable talent as a poet. Within a very short time, as a result of serf riots in Krosyn, Bahrym was sent into the army for a term of twenty-five years (military service was frequently used in the Russian Empire for punitive purposes...) Although he lived until 1891, Bahrym is not heard of again as a poet after the brief flowering of his talent as a boy in Krosyn. One poem of his survives, the opening poem of this collection...

So, this poem refers to its author being sent to the military after the riots.

Comment: Do you happen to know where in Belarus Krosyn was located?

Comment: @bobble I'm trying to work that bit out still.

Comment: Based on what I found in the Wikidata page for [the author](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q56686), Krosyn is probably [Kroshyn, also known as Krošyn](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1010122).